# Mysql query to get row from 1 table and specific column value with where clause from other table

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project ( wordpress with custom tables ) where I have merchants table and another table with 'merchant_meta' name to maintain other details like last login, billing date, token etc like shown in following screenshot

[image]

I have following query to get all merchants

```
$merchants = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY id DESC" );
```

But when I change it to following to get last_login meta key's value then it returns only merchants who has this field value.

```
$merchants = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT wp_merchants.*,wp_merchant_meta.meta_value FROM wp_merchants LEFT JOIN wp_merchant_meta ON wp_merchant_meta.merchant_id = wp_merchants.id WHERE wp_merchant_meta.meta_key = 'last_login' ORDER BY id DESC" );
```

How can I get all merchants with last_login value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all merchants, regardless of whether they have a `last_login` value or not, you need to remove the `WHERE` clause which is turning your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html)) and add that condition to the `ON` clause i.e.

```
$merchants = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_merchants.*,wp_merchant_meta.meta_value
                                 FROM wp_merchants 
                                 LEFT JOIN wp_merchant_meta ON wp_merchant_meta.merchant_id = wp_merchants.id AND wp_merchant_meta.meta_key = 'last_login'
                                 ORDER BY id DESC" );
```

Comment: Thanks for exact solution. Can you suggest me a query to get meta value for 2 different meta keys like last_login and invoice_status both ?

Comment: @VikramSingh you should ask a new question for that, it is a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Contidion `wp_merchant_meta.meta_key = 'last_login'` is a condition of tables union and it should be in JOIN statement

```
SELECT 
    wp_merchants.*,
    wp_merchant_meta.meta_value 
FROM wp_merchants 
LEFT JOIN wp_merchant_meta ON wp_merchant_meta.merchant_id = wp_merchants.id 
    AND wp_merchant_meta.meta_key = 'last_login'
```